# c0000005 exception (Access violation) while using JNI in C++

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, access-violation

I started using JNI to call Java classes from C++ some weeks ago and today I encountered a peculiar situation. I am new to C++ (familiar with Java though), so this could be a n00b error. I have this class in Java called IntArray.java and I created another class in C++ called IntArrayProxy (split in a .h and a .cpp file) in order to access its methods through JNI. I also have another source file called IntArrayProxyTest.cpp which tests the IntArrayProxy methods.

In IntArrayProxy, I use a data member jobject* intArrayObject which contains the instance of the Java class and I pass this to every method of the IntArrayProxy class. My problem is that when I use it as a pointer (jobject*), after inserting (using insert) some integers and changing some of them (using setElement), when I use the same size() method twice, the executable I create crashes giving me a c0000005 exception (Access violation).

The first thing I noticed was that there is no problem at all if I use a normal jobject (not a jobject*) and the second one was that the exception occurs when I try to call a second non-void method. insert() and setElement(int, int) are both void, so I can call them as many times as I want. I tried it with almost all the non-void methods and the same exception was thrown each time I tried to call two non-void methods.

I thought that maybe the pointer somehow changed, so I tried printing the jobject* in each method but it stayed the same. The second explanation I found in forums was that maybe the object was destroyed but I don't know how to check it and why this could happen. I spent all day searching and debugging but no luck.

I think it's irrelevant but I am using the latest (32-bit) minGW compiler on Win7(64-bit). I also use the 32-bit jvm.dll. I am using the command line to compile it (**g++ -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include\win32" IntArrayProxy.cpp IntArrayProxyTest.cpp -L"C:\Users\jEOPARd\Desktop\Creta\JNI samples" -ljvm -o IntArrayProxyTest.exe**)

Hope someone can help me!!

Thanx in advance!!

Kostis

IntArray.java

```
package SortIntArray;

public class IntArray {

private int[] arrayOfInt;
private int cursor;
private static final int CAPACITY = 5;

public IntArray() {
    arrayOfInt = new int[CAPACITY];
    cursor = 0;
}

public void insert(int n) {
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("Inserting in a full array!");
    } else {
        arrayOfInt[cursor++] = n;
    }
}

public int removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Removing from an empty array!");
        return -666;
    } else {
        return arrayOfInt[--cursor];
    }
}

private boolean isEmpty() {
    return cursor <= 0;
}

private boolean isFull() {
    return cursor >= CAPACITY;
}

public String toString() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return "Empty Array";
    }
    String s = Integer.toString(arrayOfInt[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < cursor; i++) {
        s += ", " + Integer.toString(arrayOfInt[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

public int size() {
    return cursor;
}

public int getElement(int pos) {
    return arrayOfInt[pos];
}

public void setElement(int pos, int newElement) {
    arrayOfInt[pos] = newElement;
}
}
```

IntArrayProxy.h

```
#ifndef INTARRAYPROXY_H
#define INTARRAYPROXY_H

#include <jni.h>
using namespace std;

class IntArrayProxy {
JNIEnv *env;
jclass intArrayClass;
jobject *intArrayObject; //giati oxi pointer?
public:

IntArrayProxy(JNIEnv*);

void insert(int n);
int removeLast();
string toString();
int size();
int getElement(int);
void setElement(int pos, int newElement);
jobject *getIntArrayObject();
};


#endif  /* INTARRAYPROXY_H */
```

IntArrayProxy.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "IntArrayProxy.h"

IntArrayProxy::IntArrayProxy(JNIEnv *envir) {
env = envir;
intArrayClass = env -> FindClass("SortIntArray/IntArray");
if (intArrayClass == NULL) {
    cout << "--intArrayClass = NULL\n";
    exit(0);
}
jmethodID IntArrayConstructor = env->GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "<init>", "()V");
if (IntArrayConstructor == NULL) {
    cout << "--IntArrayConstructor = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
cout << "IntArrayProxy: Got constructor\n";
jobject obj = env -> NewObject(intArrayClass, IntArrayConstructor);
intArrayObject = &obj;     // I also can't assign intArrayObject directly at the above line, I don't know why (would be glad if you could tell me)
if (*intArrayObject == NULL) {
    cout << "--*intArrayObject = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
cout << "IntArrayProxy: Object created\n";
}

void IntArrayProxy::insert(int n) {
jmethodID insertID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "insert", "(I)V");
if (insertID == NULL) {
    cout << "--insertID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
env -> CallVoidMethod(*intArrayObject, insertID, (jint) n);
}

int IntArrayProxy::removeLast() {
jmethodID removeLastID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "removeLast", "()I");
if (removeLastID == NULL) {
    cout << "--removeLastID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
return (int) (env -> CallIntMethod(*intArrayObject, removeLastID));
}

string IntArrayProxy::toString() {
jmethodID toStringID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
if (toStringID == NULL) {
    cout << "--toStringID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
jstring intArrayString = (jstring) env -> CallObjectMethod(*intArrayObject, toStringID);
string s = env -> GetStringUTFChars(intArrayString, NULL);
return s;
}

int IntArrayProxy::size(){
jmethodID sizeID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "size", "()I");
if (sizeID == NULL) {
    cout << "--sizeID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
return (int) (env -> CallIntMethod(*intArrayObject, sizeID));    
}

int IntArrayProxy::getElement(int pos) {
jmethodID getElementID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "getElement", "(I)I");
if (getElementID == NULL) {
    cout << "--getElementID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
return (int) env -> CallObjectMethod(*intArrayObject, getElementID, (jint) pos);
}

void IntArrayProxy::setElement(int pos, int newElement){
jmethodID setElementID = env -> GetMethodID(intArrayClass, "setElement", "(II)V");
if (setElementID == NULL) {
    cout << "--setElementID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
env -> CallVoidMethod(*intArrayObject, setElementID, (jint) pos, (jint) newElement);    
}

jobject *IntArrayProxy::getIntArrayObject(){
return intArrayObject;
}
```

IntArrayProxyTest.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "IntArrayProxy.h"

int main() {
cout << "--Starting..\n";
JavaVM *jvm; /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env; /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\jEOPARd\\Desktop\\Creta\\JNI samples\\JNI tests\\build\\classes";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
cout << "--Creating VM..\n";
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, &vm_args);
cout << "--VM created successfully!!\n";
delete options;

cout << "--Finding IntArray class..\n";
IntArrayProxy *intArrayProxy = new IntArrayProxy(env);
if (env->ExceptionOccurred())
    env->ExceptionDescribe();


intArrayProxy -> insert(1);
intArrayProxy -> insert(10);
intArrayProxy -> insert(3);
intArrayProxy -> insert(88);
intArrayProxy -> insert(32);

intArrayProxy ->setElement(2, 5);
intArrayProxy ->setElement(3, 7);    

cout << "Size: " << intArrayProxy -> size() << endl;
cout << "Size: " << intArrayProxy -> size() << endl;

cout << "--Destroying VM..\n";
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
cout << "--Done!!!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try reducing the amount of code to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proxy constructor:

intArrayObject = &obj;

You're taking the address of a variable on the stack.  When the constructor exits, the address is no longer valid, hence the crash.

The intArrayObject (in the header) should be a jobject, not a jobject*, and the various uses of it should be changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanx Dave. What you say makes a lot of sense. I have some questions though. Why does it crash only at the non-void methods and not the void ones? And why does it produce correct results when it doesn't crash? (When I'm using the first non-void method (size() here), the results are correct)

Comment: Because the memory is on the stack, the memory is still present, so it will not always crash.  However, it could be overwritten at any time (possibly the first call you make, possibly later), and once it has been overwritten, it's fairly likely to crash.